# Can't import module after manually installing

Tags: python, module

I have installed the module pynauty via https://web.cs.dal.ca/~peter/software/pynauty/html/install.html.  Everything seemed to work, and I believe that it is fully installed.  However, when I try importing it in python shell, it says there is no module named pynauty. I think I am missing a final step in installing.  Does anyone know what that final step would be?

Comment: It says it would install to `~/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`. What is the output when you type `which python`?

Comment: When I type which python it outputs /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

I just grappled with this problem myself. As creimers pointed out, the setup script calls `pip install --user .` which installs pynauty in `~/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`.

What you probably want is to have it installed in `/usr/bin/python` (or whatever pops up when you type `which python`). Assuming you already called `make user-ins`, all you need to do is run

```
sudo pip install .
```

from inside where you extracted and built your pynauty.